# Pass in positional arguments to Bash function

Tags: bash

I have a simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

function main() {

    declare -a ARGS=(
        --cell=""
    )

    echo "${ARGS[@]}"
}

main "$@"
```

I want to be able to modify the `cell` flag through a command line prompt, and I thought the following would work:

```
sh launch_training.sh -- --cell=test
```

However, this doesn't seem to override it in the function itself. Am I formatting my command line prompt incorrectly?

Comment: Have you tried putting `ARGS+=("$@")` after the declare command?

Comment: Try `declare -a ARGS=("$@")` or use `$1,$2, $3` and/or `$@` directly.

Comment: Look up tutorials on how to parse command-line arguments in Bash.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect to happen, or why you supposed that the code you present was a plausible attempt at that.  Certainly, the only observable behavior I would expect is the output of your `echo` command -- which takes no account of arguments to the script or to the `main()` function within -- being printed to the script's standard output.

Comment: Use a variable to hold the value of the `cell` flag, and give it a default value. Then use `getopts` to process the command-line arguments, and update the variable when processing `--cell`.

Comment: tip: either use `bash launch_training.sh` or don't use bash-isms in your script

Comment: `sh` is not bash. There's no guaranteed support for arrays in anything you start with `sh`. (`sh` also doesn't guarantee support for the abomination that is `function funcname() {`, which merges the incompatible legacy ksh syntax `function funcname {` and the modern POSIX sh syntax `funcname() {` in a way that's incompatible with **both** legacy ksh and POSIX sh).

Comment: Also, keep your own variables out of all-caps namespace, which are used for variables with meaning to the shell itself or OS-provided tools. Using lowercase names for your own variables prevents you from changing special names unintentionally.